# AMP form within an AMP carousel slider

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to add a form over multiple slides. Where the user can fill it some details on one slide then go to the next to fill out more.

It works within the amp-carousel. However when the submit or fields are on another slide it doesn't work.

Is there a reason for this? Or a way around this?

```
<amp-carousel height="100vh" layout="fixed-height" type="slides">
      <div>
       <form method="post" action-xhr="send-form.php">
      <div class="blue-box">
         <input type="text" name="name" required  />
         Your telephone number:<br>
         <input type="text" name="phone" required />    
      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="red-box">
      Your email address:<br>
           <input type="text" name="email"  required />
      </div> 

    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="blue-box">
        Your message:<br>
           <textarea name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="green-box">
        <input type="submit" value="" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:#000;"/>    
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </amp-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to "hack" a [multi page flow form](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/multi_page_flow/).

You can't do this with amp-carousel because when AMP renders a carousel, it uses all HTML in it to create a slide. It doesn't link up the slides, so each slide's HTML is on its own. So what AMP sees in the first slide is this code:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="send-form.php">
      <div class="blue-box">
         <input type="text" name="name" required  />
         Your telephone number:<br>
         <input type="text" name="phone" required />    
      </div>

    </div>
```

Then AMP sees that the closing `</form>` tag is missing, so its adds it to the first slide and the rest of the fields are *outside* the form hence why you can't submit it since the `submit` field is on the last slide.

Here is a screenshot how your code in the first slide is rendered:

[image]

AMP automatically closes the `form` element.

So if you want to add the whole form to the first slide, it should work. If you really want a [multi page flow form](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/multi_page_flow/), use `amp-bind` instead.